# Where is it indicated: how to sign out of this website?

Tags: support

No button, menu item or instruction on how to SIGN OUT.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't specify a device (phone, PC, Mac etc.) in your question. On a phone (at least in portrait orientation) the smaller screen width means there are fewer icons displayed. Therefore you may have to "scroll" (swipe) the top icons sideways to the left, to see the "hamburger button" (see below) on the right side of the screen, in my experience.

Anyway, on a PC, as shown on the image below:

---

[image: How to logout of the site]

---

1. Click the "hamburger" button.
2. Click the "log out" link.
3. Then you will see a page similar to the one below (depending on which Stack Exchange sites you have logged into):

---

[image: Logout page]

---

4. Choose whether or not to log out on all devices.
5. Click the big "Log out" button.

---

A relevant Meta.SE page is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23102/logging-out-of-stack-overflow-or-any-stack-exchange-site/23103#23103). The latest update in that answer seems to agree with the current UI (some comments below that answer are obsolete, as the answer has since been updated). Note that the overall webpage design / layout (and the location of the logout link) may change in future.

Since this UI design is the same across all of SE, not specific to Electronics.SE, then if you want a deeper discussion the appropriate place is on the [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) site.